Kafka Stream Aggregation based on Multiple Keys
I'm encountering a challenge with two devices that generate similar data payloads. My objective is to merge these payloads and perform aggregation based on both timestamp and measurement type. In aggregation I mean in this case to just add values of value field. To better illustrate, refer to this image:

I'm relatively new to streaming applications and lack expertise in this area. I've considered various approaches, such as creating five topics and distributing data based on timestamp modulo 5, then utilizing Kafka windowing. Additionally, I'm aware of stream joins, where data can be joined based on a key. Considering my scenario involves joining streams based on two keys, I've contemplated creating a hash of these keys as another key for the join operation, though I'm uncertain about the specifics.
Could someone suggest a suitable solution for this challenge? While Kafka is an option, I'm open to exploring alternatives. We are using Python for this and if solution will be in python that would be the best, and if not we will consider using other languages. Thank you in advance.

Why do your sensor produce messages in different topics if it is about the same measurement object ? In kafka-streams, you can choose to aggregate by the key of the topic, or by a field inside values. In the latter case, repartitioning will be made
